# Drop-in CRUD web application

Tags: postgresql, web-applications, crud

## Background

A simple database with about 20 tables, sprinkled with unique constraints, primary keys, and foreign key relationships. This is a database for internal use only. Only two or three people will have direct access to the data. Only one of those people is qualified to be a DBA.

The database was developed using DbSchema and PostgreSQL 9.1.

The project itself is meant to be a quick-and-dirty prototype, but using clean data. Authentication and security are non-issues.

## Problem

I'd like to supply a simple web-based CRUD application so that any data errors can be resolved without having to get the DBA involved.

## Question

What software would you recommend that exposes a simple web interface that allows non-DBAs the ability to update data?

## Example

To clarify, if it was a Java application, here is the simplicity I envision:

1. Download a `jar` file (e.g., `crud-web-app.jar`).
2. Run:

   ```
   java -jar crud-web-app.jar --username=postgres --password=password --host=localhost:5432 --database=database --listen=127.0.0.1:8080
   ```
3. Browse to 127.0.0.1:8080
4. Select a table (one click).
5. Edit data (saves over AJAX).

## Related

[phpPgAdmin](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/) comes close, but I thought there might be something simpler (i.e., less intimidating for non-DBAs).

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate CRUD without writing any code:

- [PHP Generator](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/postgresql/phpgenerator/)

PostgreSQL PHP Generator is a PostgreSQL GUI frontend that allows you to generate high-quality PHP scripts for selected tables, views, and queries for updates over the web.

## Demo Page

- http://demo.sqlmaestro.com/

The free version is fairly extensive, the commercial version includes a vast number of features. Using the tool, it took about 30 minutes (from the software download) to generate CRUD pages for two dozen tables. The software automatically provides drop-downs for foreign key relationships.

## Example Output

The following screen shot shows the output from running the generator:

[image: Example Editor]

Comment: the windows executable works nicely with linux using wine

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [DaDaBIK](http://www.dadabik.org), you can create a CRUD front-end/web application without coding.