# Crud on Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I need to allow one single user to make CRUD on an Amazon RDS db. I'm a BI dev and dont know a bunch of web dev. This specific user need a GUI interface to make these CRUDS, is there any tool that help me out on this or I'm obligated to develop something? I'm wondering some SAAS.

Comment: Which database engine specifically?

Comment: Then it turns out your question is a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697330/drop-in-crud-web-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I followed the tutorial presented by @mark and it really helped me. Thanks ([Drop-in CRUD web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697330/drop-in-crud-web-application))